# Condición if a error 500

Tags: php

¿como puedo agregar una condición a la función en php si se declara una clase? 
El error 500 se genera cuando la zona del flete no coincide con el area del servicio brindado.

```
class PException extends \Exception {
  public function __construct( $message, $code = 500, \Exception $previous = null ) {
    parent::__construct( $message, $code, $previous );
  }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Primero que todo deberías mostrarnos cuál es la función que te saca el error. Segundo no sabemos qué es la Zona del flete, por lo tanto creo que debes explicar mejor tu problema y adjuntar más código

Comment: @CristianAndrésHiguita buscaba una forma de que en lugar de buscar si la latitud y longitu de un punto se encontraba en un poligono, podria evitar la respuesta erronea de un json. Es posible?

Comment: Muéstrame como construyes tu JSON

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione con `if ($response['status'] === 404) {` por si alguien le sirve.
Gracias!

Comment: Y cómo usaste esa validación o dónde?

Comment: Por favor, sé más generoso con la respuesta.